# Using Thread interrupt to wake up a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Are there any drawbacks to regularly wake up a thread on Android using Thread.interrupt.
The thread loop looks similar to this:

```
public void run()
{
   while(true)
   {
       try
       {
          wait();
       }
       catch(InterruptedException e)
       {
          performWork();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess it will be slower since it will create an Exception for it. BTW how will you know if the tread is interrupted by you or some other mechanism?

Comment: Why not use the actual `wait`/`notify` mechanism, instead of (ab)using `wait` to sleep forever?

Comment: A major drawback would be that it's hard to think of a use case for such construction.

Comment: As @immibis suggested, use Object `wait`/`notify`

Comment: use a HandlerThread and send a message in order to perform some work on demand

Comment: @Burkhard, you put your finger on the fundamental flaw of Thread.interrupt():  There is only one, and nobody is really sure what it is supposed to mean.  You can carefully construct your _own_ code to do something useful when an interrupt happens, but what if it happens when you are calling into a 3rd party library?  Unless the library doc is explicit about its interrupt behavior, or you have inspected the library source code; the only truly safe thing you can do is clean up, and shut down the JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's a horrible way to code. `interrupt()` will for instance throw an Exception if the Thread is blocked in I/O and is not made to be used like this.

Instead, use [notify/wait](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/wait_notify_how_to.shtml) which is made for this. Something like this in `run()`:

```
synchronized (this) {
   while (conditionForWaiting) {
      try {
         wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

}
performWork();
```

And to notify the thread that conditionForWaiting is changed:

```
synchronized (threadInstance) {
   threadInstance.notify();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the semantics of interrupt: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()

Comment: @JE42 Interrupt is basically there as a built-in function for allowing graceful termination of a Thread, and is best to be used for that.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't aware of all the additional semantics that you pointed out.